# How to remove words from string and divided that string into an array

Tags: php

i want to let only one color word from each option
from this:

```
$colors = '< option value="black">black< /option>< option value="gold">gold< /option >';
```

to this :

```
$colors = 'black gold';
```

after that i want to enter the colors to an array like this
How to remove words from string and divided that string to an array

like this

```
Array
        (
            [0] => black 
            [1] => gold
        )
```

Comment: You would use the `explode` method within PhP to split a string by a specific delimiter.  It would then be put into an array like you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to extract the values:

```
$colors = '< option value="black">black< /option>< option value="gold">gold< /option >';
preg_match_all('/value="([^"]+)"/', $colors, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => black 
        [1] => gold
    )
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/QmhJD)

You can also do this using PHP's [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class although it may be overkill for your example:

```
$colors = '< option value="black">black< /option>< option value="gold">gold< /option >';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(str_replace('< ', '<', $colors));
$values = array();
$attributes = array();
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('option') as $option) {
    $values[] = $option->nodeValue;
    $attributes[] = $option->getAttribute('value');
}
print_r($values);
print_r($attributes);
```

Note that it was necessary to correct the HTML by removing the space between `<` and `option`. The advantage of this method is that it easily gets either values or attributes. Output:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => black 
        [1] => gold
    )
Array
    (
        [0] => black 
        [1] => gold
    )
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/oNUg3)